# How would I fix this code? (if-statements)

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am doing a beginner Java course. I'm not sure how I would store the variables for each if statement. This is what my code looks like:

```
    // Variables for the final sum of all even numbers
    int evensum1,evensum2,evensum3,evensum4;
    if (oneeven < 10){
        evensum1 = oneeven;
    }
    if (twoeven < 10){     
        evensum2 = twoeven;
    }
    if (threeeven < 10){    
        evensum3 = threeeven;
    }
    if (foureven < 10){    
        evensum4 = foureven;
    }

    // Determine if the digits have 2 characters (>= 10); if yes, separate them
    else if (oneeven >= 10){
    // Convert each multiplied number to a string to separate them again        
        String char1even = "" + oneeven;
        char sep11 = char1even.charAt(0);
        char sep12 = char1even.charAt(1);
        int val11 = Character.getNumericValue(sep11);
        int val12 = Character.getNumericValue(sep12);
        evensum1 = val11 + val12;
    }
    else if (twoeven >= 10){
        String char2even = "" + twoeven;
        char sep21 = char2even.charAt(0);
        char sep22 = char2even.charAt(1);
        int val21 = Character.getNumericValue(sep21);
        int val22 = Character.getNumericValue(sep22);
        evensum2 = val21 + val22;
    }
    else if (threeeven >= 10){
        String char3even = "" + threeeven;
        char sep31 = char3even.charAt(0);
        char sep32 = char3even.charAt(1);
        int val31 = Character.getNumericValue(sep31);
        int val32 = Character.getNumericValue(sep32);
        evensum3 = val31 + val32;
    }   
    else if (foureven >= 10){
        String char4even = "" + twoeven;
        char sep41 = char4even.charAt(0);
        char sep42 = char4even.charAt(1);
        int val41 = Character.getNumericValue(sep41);
        int val42 = Character.getNumericValue(sep42);
        evensum4 = val41 + val42;
    }

    // Add the separate even digits together
    int finevensum = evensum1 + evensum2 + evensum3 + evensum4;
    System.out.println(finevensum);
```

I am having trouble with the second last line. What I want to do is get EITHER a 2-digit OR 1-digit first/second/third/number. Depending on how many digits the number has, the sum of the number will be different. I want to add the numbers together at the end.
How would I store the values in each variable so they are available to use even after the if statement?

Comment: What should this code do?
FYI:  15%10 = 5   and ((int) 15/10) = 1

Comment: declare/use global variable

Comment: I think the problem is how you're using `else`. Delete all the occurrences of `else` and it may work. Use some debug outputs to determine which of the conditional blocks are being executed.

Comment: This is part of a program that checks the last digit of a 9digit Social Security Number. This section has received the inputted SSN and is determining if the (even-placed numbers * 2) have one digit or two digits. If there are 2 digits, it separates the digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
if (foureven < 10){    
        evensum4 = foureven;
}

// Determine if the digits have 2 characters (>= 10); if yes, separate them
else if (oneeven >= 10){
```

Then the `else` referring the **last** `if`. So it'll be entered if `foureven < 10` (regardless of `oneeven`).

You should do something like that:

```
if (oneeven < 10){
     evensum1 = oneeven;
} else { ... //Note that it's redundant to write oneeven >= 10
```

(Do this for the rest `if` statements)

Comment: +1 - Yes. There's no such thing as `else if` it's better for beginning programmers to put `else` and `if` on their own lines with their own `{ ... }` blocks, in my opinion.